# inflater does not decompress all the compressed bytes

Tags: java, zip, compression

Deflater compresses a byte array consisting of bytes from 0 to 99 (length is 100)
The compressed byte array is passed to Inflater as input for decompressing.
Returned length from the decompressor is missing 3 bytes from the original list.

Following is code :

```
        byte orig[] = new byte[100];
        IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i -> orig[i] = (byte) i);


        System.out.println("OrigLength: " + orig.length);

        byte[] compressed = new byte[orig.length];


        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(orig);
        deflater.finish();
        int compressedLength = deflater.deflate(compressed);
        deflater.end();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("CompressedLength::" + compressedLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < compressedLength; i++) {
            System.out.print(compressed[i] + " ");
        }


        Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
        decompresser.setInput(compressed, 0, compressedLength);
        byte[] result = new byte[compressedLength];
        int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);
        decompresser.end();

        System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("DecompressedLength::" + resultLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
            System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------");
```

Output:

> OrigLength: 100
>
> ---
>
> CompressedLength::100
>
> 120 -100 99 96 100 98 102 97 101 99 -25 -32 -28 -30 -26 -31 -27 -29 23
>   16 20 18 22 17 21 19 -105 -112 -108 -110 -106 -111 -107 -109 87 80 84
>   82 86 81 85 83 -41 -48 -44 -46 -42 -47 -43 -45 55 48 52 50 54 49 53 51
>   -73 -80 -76 -78 -74 -79 -75 -77 119 112 116 114 118 113 117 115 -9 -16 -12 -14 > -10 -15 -11 -13 15 8 12 10 14 9 13 11 -113 -120 -116 -118 -114 -119 -115 -117 79 72
>
> ---
>
> DecompressedLength::97
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
>   27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
>   50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72
>   73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95
>   96
>
> ---
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Decompressed length is 97 and original length is 100. Can you please suggest what is the problem with my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although is not clear but i found the following ,

It is not the inflater that is at fault but the deflater.

Deflater when compressing data i surprisingly noticed that the number of bytes are increased than the original uncompressed data.For instance the above compressed data array has 100 elements because the array was constructed with size 100.

However if i increase the size of the compressed array size which is arbitrarily to say 200 and then use that array then the deflate method would return me a value 108 (here  8 bytes extra than the original 100). This is puzzling me because for me to understand i need to know what exactly is a deflate compression and how the algorithm works which i am going through it.

so here is the updated code,

```
byte orig[] = new byte[100];

        IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i -> orig[i] = (byte) i);

        System.out.println("OrigLength: " + orig.length);

        byte[] compressed = new byte[orig.length * 2]; // double it arbitrarily chosen 


        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(orig);
        deflater.finish();
        int compressedLength = 0;
        compressedLength = deflater.deflate(compressed);
        deflater.end();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("CompressedLength::" + compressedLength); //now this will be 108
        for (int i = 0; i < compressedLength; i++) {
            System.out.print(compressed[i] + " ");
        }


        Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
        byte[] result = new byte[orig.length];
        decompresser.setInput(compressed, 0, compressedLength);
        int resultLength  = decompresser.inflate(result);
        decompresser.end();

        System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("DecompressedLength::" + resultLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
            System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------");
```

Output:

OrigLength: 100

---

**CompressedLength::108**  // this is the point of concern 8 bytes extra

### 120 -100 99 96 100 98 102 97 101 99 -25 -32 -28 -30 -26 -31 -27 -29 23 16 20 18 22 17 21 19 -105 -112 -108 -110 -106 -111 -107 -109 87 80 84 82 86 81 85 83 -41 -48 -44 -46 -42 -47 -43 -45 55 48 52 50 54 49 53 51 -73 -80 -76 -78 -74 -79 -75 -77 119 112 116 114 118 113 117 115 -9 -16 -12 -14 -10 -15 -11 -13 15 8 12 10 14 9 13 11 -113 -120 -116 -118 -114 -119 -115 -117 79 72 76 74 6 0 -117 124 19 87

DecompressedLength::100

### 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look at this example:

https://github.com/DawnScience/dawn-common/blob/master/org.dawb.common.util/src/org/dawb/common/util/list/PrimitiveArrayEncoder.java#L95

```
public static String compress(final String expanded) {

    try {
        byte[] input = expanded.getBytes("US-ASCII");

        // Compress the bytes
        byte[] output = new byte[input.length];
        Deflater compresser = new Deflater();
        compresser.setInput(input);
        compresser.finish();
        final int size  = compresser.deflate(output);

        return new String(output, 0, size, "US-ASCII");
    } catch (Exception ne) {
        ne.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Inflate a string
 * @param compressed
 * @return Inflated string.
 */
public static String expand(final String compressed) {

    try {
        final byte[] output = compressed.getBytes("US-ASCII");

        // Decompress the bytes
        Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
        decompresser.setInput(output, 0, output.length);

        byte[] result = new byte[output.length*2];
        int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);
        decompresser.end();

        // Decode the bytes into a String
        return new String(result, 0, resultLength, "US-ASCII");

    } catch (Exception ne) {
        ne.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: well i am using plain bytes instead of converting string to bytes. I am wondering what is the issue with my code that inflater is not returning all the bytes that originally were compressed.

Answer (score 0):

You might find some ideas here:

```
private static byte[] readCompressed(final Repository db,
        final AnyObjectId id) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    final FileInputStream objStream = new FileInputStream(db.toFile(id));
    final byte[] compressed;
    try {
        compressed = new byte[objStream.available()];
        int off = 0;
        while (off < compressed.length)
            off += objStream.read(compressed, off, compressed.length - off);
    } finally {
        objStream.close();
    }
    return compressed;
}
```

Full code here:
http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=50oAEc5CLFonr_2GPq0IoqxVPw8&cid=6SVb15jezXE&s=inflater%20does%20not%20decompress%20all%20the%20compressed%20bytes&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&projSelected=false&filterChecked,=true&mp,=1&filterChecked=true&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1#L26